# PowerShell "net use" error

Tags: powershell

I am trying use PowerShell to access a folder on a remote server:

1. I use pc1 to set up a local account and share a folder to the local account
2. I use pc2 to use the command below to access the remote folder:

   ```
   net use \\<pc1 ip>\SampleData $password /USER:.\test
   ```

But I will get the error below:

> net : System error 53 has occurred.
>   The network path was not found.

But if I use the command below, which doesn't have the account info:

```
net use \\<pc1 ip>\SampleData
```

It will succeed.

What is wrong with the first command?

Comment: I also used net use \\<pc1 ip>\SampleData $password /USER:pc1\test but failed

Comment: I tried the first command and it worked as expected, so my first conclusion would be that $password is the wrong-object-type which messes up the command

Comment: The issue is `/USER:.\test` should be `/USER:username` ( without the `.\ ` ).  In your case `/USER:test`.

Comment: Hi kutan, I tested your command, but still have the same problem. Thanks

Comment: Hi Paxz, I tried to input password diretly in the command: net  \\<pc1 ip>\SampleData "truepassword" /USER:.\test     but still got the same error

Comment: Well if net use without Credentials works when used from pc2, the command should be `net use \\<pc1 ip>\SampleData $password /USER:pc2\<youruser>` shouldnt it?

Comment: Hi Paxz, I am using my account to run the powershell, but my account is the personal account. Need to use a general account to access that remote folder. Thanks!

Comment: `.` is a shorthand for the local computer, so you're trying to map a share from a remote host (PC1) while authenticating with a local account of PC2. I would expect `net use \\pc1\share pw /user:pc1\test` to have worked. If it didn't you need to provide more detail (full error message from that attempt and the relevant entries from the security eventlog on PC1.

Comment: I simply suspect a credential issue. Presumably you do not allow browsing on the remote device (which explains the `network path was not found` error) and have `remember my credentials` set (which explains why it works without). I see no relation with PowerShell, in other words; **What have from the Command Prompt?** (Run `cmd.exe`). Also exclude the `Net Use` command itself: **What happens from Windows Explorer?** This PC --> Map a Network Drive --> check: `Connect using different credentials`

Comment: Hi all, Thank you for your comments. Finally I use another pc to access the source folder and found able to access. I guess should be the security settings from my company for different pcs are different.